# How to show Laravel model with belongsToMany connection if has specified connection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have this product model:

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'product_categories');
}
```

And in my controller:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    return Product::with([
        'categories' => function($categories) use ($request) {
            // ...
        }
    ]);
}
```

If I try to use `$request` in the `categories` function it's search only in categories, but shows all products.

How do I show **only** that products whitch has defined categories in `$request->category_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use the `whereHas` keyword in laravel:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    return  Product::with('categories')
      ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('category_id', $request->category_id);
    })->get();
}
```

Here is the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You can search it in following way:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    return Product::with('categories')
            ->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use (request) {
                $q->where('id', $request->category_id);
            });
}
```